# xparse verbatim with newline

Tags: latex3, xparse

I'm trying to define a simple command using `xparse` and it's `verbatim` argument:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\macro{v}{#1}
```

but see

```
! LaTeX error: "xparse/verbatim-newline"
!
! Verbatim argument of \macrocode ended by end of line.
!
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
```

when the argument is multiple lines of code (i.e., contains a new line):

```
\macro{This
Is
A
Test}
```

but it has no problem for something like

```
  \macro{This    Is    A    Test}
```

In my case, I need it to work with new lines.

Update:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{luatex,xparse}
\directlua{tex.enableprimitives('',tex.extraprimitives())}
\begin{document}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\macro}{+v}{\directlua{print("\luaescapestring{#1}")}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\macroa}{+v}{#1}

\macro{
This
Is
A
Test
}

\macroa{
This
Is
A
Test
}

\end{document}
```

macro prints "ThisIsATest" without newlines. I need to print **Exactly** what is passed to the macro. macroa gives fi   Thisfi   Isfi   Afi   Testfi.

BTW, here is a MWE of it working but I want to "wrap" the behavior inside a macro for convenience:

```
\documentclass{book}   
\usepackage{luatex}    
\directlua{tex.enableprimitives('',tex.extraprimitives())}    
\begin{document}

\endlinechar`\^^J%
\catcode`\^^M=13%
\directlua{print("\luaescapestring\expandafter{\detokenize{%
This
Is
A
Test
}}")}%
\catcode`\^^M=5

\end{document}
```

**EXCEPT** Some random characters are output to the pdf (In my working example this doesn't happen because, I guess, I'm using a different font encoding).

Comment: The LuaTeX part here is really nothing to do with `xparse`, as far as I can see. to me, it looks like it would make a better question separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the lines printed in the log file and no output in the PDF with this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{luatex}
\directlua{tex.enableprimitives('',tex.extraprimitives())}

\def\myprint{%
  \begingroup
  \endlinechar`\^^J%
  \catcode`\^^M=13%
  \myprintaux}
\def\myprintaux#1#2{%
  \directlua{print("\luaescapestring\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}")}\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\myprint
{This
is
a
test
}

\end{document}
```

You need to use that form (the closing brace must be on a line of its own).

Comment: Can you explain what the macro is doing? I'm a bit confused on why it does not print to the pdf.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance That's what I assumed from `print` and not `tex.print`

Comment: Not sure if the catcode assignment is needed, since the end-line character is not `^^M` but `^^J` with your setting.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Try without it

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is how you new to use the \begingroup and \endgroup and split the macro up into two parts like that.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance The macros are split into two parts because the catcode changes has to be made *before* the argument is absorbed.

Comment: ok, But then why does your method not print the strange characters to the pdf when mine does? (they seem essentially to do the same thing)

Comment: @AbstractDissonance I change the category code of `^^M` before absorbing the argument and `\myprintaux` also absorbs one token more.

Answer (score 3):

As covered in the [`xparse` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xparse), the `v` argument type is very similar to `\verb`, and has to be ended within a line. You can grab multiple lines using the 'long' indicator, `+`:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\macro}{+v}{#1}
```

You should note that you will get

```
This^^MIs^^MA^^MTest
```

when you grab verbatim here (*i.e.* you get end-of-line tokens, not `\par`).

Comment: Ok, using `+` stops the error but now I do not get end of lines at all. I'm printing out the argument to the console using lualatex and there are no new-lines in the statement. See my update:

Comment: @AbstractDissonance 'Works for me' with an up to date TL2012, but you don't need `\detokenize` here as you've already grabbed verbatim material. As I say in the answer, if you check the argument (using `\showtokens`) you will see the `^^M` are there.

Comment: Maybe this luaescapestring is messing with the newlines. But see my update for a working example that doesn't use a macro. Using your method I still do not get new lines but just extra spaces and `fi` for newlines.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance [not tested] Try adding `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nxx }` somewhere before defining the macro, and instead of using `#1` directly in your macro definition, you can start by replacing all `^^M` by `^^J`, for instance by storing in a variable `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}`, replacing with `\tl_replace_all:Nxx \l_tmpa_tl { \iow_char:N \^^M } { \iow_char:N \^^J }` and using `\l_tmpa_tl` instead of `#1` later on.  Another option is to fiddle around with the values of `\endlinechar` and `\newlinechar` (try combinations with the values `10` and `13`).