# Unmodified Source Code 

Tags: macros, spacing, luatex

I have a macro that helps me print out(or do anything really) source code in various ways using lua:

see: [xparse verbatim with newline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70719/xparse-verbatim-with-newline)

The macro is

```
\def\SourceCode{%
  \begingroup%
  \endlinechar`\^^J%
  \catcode`\\=12\catcode`\^^M=12\catcode`\#=12\catcode`\~=12\catcode`\%=12\catcode`\^=12\catcode`\_=12\catcode`\@=12\catcode`\ =12\catcode`\|=12%
  \SourceCodeAux}%
\def\SourceCodeAux#1#2{\endgroup\directlua{print("\luaescapestring{#1}")}}%
```

In this case we just print the code to the console to view if it is correct.

The issue is that `\detokenize` adds a space after macro's. Is there any way to stop this behavior or reverse it? (I'm thinking if we could use a different, non-visible or not used in the source code block, escape character then maybe it will be possible?)

---

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{luatex}\directlua{tex.enableprimitives('',tex.extraprimitives())}

\def\SourceCode{%
  \begingroup%
  \endlinechar`\^^J%
  \catcode`\\=12\catcode`\^^M=12\catcode`\#=12\catcode`\~=12\catcode`\%=12\catcode`\^=12\catcode`\_=12\catcode`\@=12\catcode`\ =12\catcode`\|=12%
  \SourceCodeAux}%
\def\SourceCodeAux#1#2{\endgroup\directlua{print("\luaescapestring{#1}")}}%


\begin{document}

\SourceCode{
   \documentclass{minimal}
   \def\SourceCode{%
      \begingroup%
      \obeyspaces%
      \endlinechar`\^^J%
      \catcode`\^^M=13%
      \SourceCodeAux}%
   \def\SourceCodeAux#1#2{\directlua{print("\luaescapestring\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}")}\endgroup}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post your complete source? I can't reproduce any difference between LuaTeX and PDFTeX wrt `\obeyspaces`

Comment: It's `\detokenize` that adds spaces after control words.

Comment: @Mr.Gundla That essentially is the complete source. Add documentclass and wrap it with begin{document} and end{document}. I'm using lualatex. Are you saying that commenting out `\obeyspaces` does not change the output?

Comment: @AbstractDissonance Try `\edef\x{\detokenize{\abc\xyz}}\show\x` and you'll see spaces after `\abc` and `\xyz`. It's part of the workings of `\detokenize` (and of `\write` also).

Comment: @AbstractDissonance It might help to have a complete code to play with. It makes it easier to get started, but there is of course no promise that I can help :)

Comment: @Mr.Gundla Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `\catcode'\\=12` and removing the `\detokenizer` seems to effectively detokenize the code block:

```
\def\SourceCode{%
  \begingroup%
  \endlinechar`\^^J%
  \catcode`\\=12\catcode`\^^M=12\catcode`\#=12\catcode`\~=12\catcode`\%=12\catcode`\^=12\catcode`\_=12\catcode`\@=12\catcode`\ =12\catcode`\|=12%      
  \SourceCodeAux}%
\def\SourceCodeAux#1#2{\endgroup\directlua{print("\luaescapestring{#1}")}}%
```