# understanding makeatletter with minted / minipage / colorboxes

Tags: macros, minted

I found this cool posting for allowing you to include a minted or lstlisting environment inside of a call to a macro:

https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/54#issuecomment-58233667

The code

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode`\{=1
  \catcode`\}=2
  \endlinechar`\^^J
  \foo@i}
\newcommand{\foo@i}[1]{%
  \endgroup\scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \expandafter\foo@cleanup}
\def\foo@cleanup#1^^J{#1 }
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71049/allow-macro-to-end-without-new-line
\makeatother
```

I understand that I can use saveboxes, but I do not want to.  Substitution `\foo` for `\question`, I am trying to implement the equivalent of

```
\newcommand{\question}[1]{
     \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{gray!11}{
         \begin{minipage}[t]{0.97\textwidth}
             \vspace*{1ex}
             #1
             \vspace*{1ex}
         \end{minipage}
     }
 }
```

The problem is after hours of digging around the web, I can't get a clear picture on how this would work.  I've tried to make new environments, play with `tcolorbox`, a bunch of different things.  I thought I was making progress when I used `\minipage{...}` in the first part before `\foo@i`, and then `\endminipage` before the `\endgroup`, and quickly realized that this was not doing what I thought it was.  The same goes for `\tcolorbox` and `\endtcolorbox` in the same locations.

So basically, is it possible to `begin` something like a `minipage` or `(t/f)colorbox` and wrap it around this?  I cannot put something like `\tcolorbox[colors etc]{\foo@i}}` as the last line (right after `\endlinechar`), or really any other variant.  At this point, endlessly permuting where these commands go is fruitless and I feel I need to be doing something differently.

Thank you for any pointers, e.g. a hacky way to get `{` and `}` in.  I tried to use the catcodes but I think I'm missing the bigger picture.

The idea would be to use the macro in a situation like this:

```
\question{
\paragraph*{5: A question from my prof}
Consider some stuff about things i want you to solve:
\begin{minted}{matlab}
  for i = 1:n
    x(i) = x(i) + 1;
  end
\end{minted}
Show that this is a thing that can be done yay.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want. It takes the linked example, and adds in your `\fcolorbox`, `minipage`, etc.

The basic idea is that the macro argument needs to be captured in such a way that an absolute minimum of characters have special meanings (catcodes) so that almost all characters can appear literally, but also so that line endings are preserved (`\endlinechar`).  Then, after the argument is captured, the next macro uses `\scantokens` to retokenize everything (including preserved line endings) so that it behaves normally where it is actually used.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\question}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode`\{=1
  \catcode`\}=2
  \endlinechar`\^^J
  \question@i}
\newcommand{\question@i}[1]{%
  \endgroup
  \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{gray!11}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.97\textwidth}%
    \vspace*{1ex}%
    \scantokens{#1\noexpand}\par%
    \vspace*{1ex}%
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
  \expandafter\question@cleanup}
\def\question@cleanup#1^^J{#1 }
\makeatother
```

Comment: Works like a charm!!!  Thank you very much for explaining how this is working, I was misunderstanding how it was expanding everything out but this makes a lot more sense :)  It's like I'm relearning tex all over again. Edit: lol i just realized it was **your** post to start out with, thanks again!